# How old is Vimes?

Tags: terry-pratchett, discworld, age

At the end of *Unseen Academicals* (or, if it's easier to place, *Thud!*), how old is Sam Vimes?  Is it possible to even figure out what his age is?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

We see Vimes in his forties to fifties, but his exact age is not given out in a consistent way. Terry Pratchett has stated that each book happens on a slightly different leg of the [Trousers of Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternate_history#Alternate_history_in_the_contemporary_fantasy_genre): [“There are no inconsistencies in the Discworld books; ocassionally, however, there are alternate pasts.”](http://www.lspace.org/books/pqf/alt-fan-pratchett.html).

[*Night Watch*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_Watch_%28Discworld%29) has uncharacteristically precise indications about Vimes's age, what with

> Vimes traveling through time and meeting his earlier self

*Night Watch* opens and closes on the 30th anniversary of the Glorious Revolution of the Twenty-Fifth of May. At the time of the revolution, Vimes is a rookie recruit to the Watch; I seem to remember his age being stated as 16, and in any case in his late teens. That would make him 46 when *Night Watch* ends and his son is born, and therefore 47 or 48 in [*Thud!*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thud!).

Other Watch books make him a little older than that. In fact, even *Thud!* states that Vimes was a blackboard monitor “in that little street school more than forty-five years ago” and that he was 6 years old at the time, hence he would have been at least 51 in *Thud!*. I seem to remember Vimes being fiftyish in earlier books, though I can't find a quote to back it up at the moment.

Comment: Eh? Sam is *born* in *Night Watch*, @Pureferret, and he already has a favourite 6-o'clock story by *Thud*.

Answer (score 1):

I recall Sam saying in Thud! that he was a bit older than Sally, who was 51.

Comment: Of course, Young Sam was born in Night Watch and is 6 in Snuff

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This would be a much better answer if you could find a quote to back this up.